# Baking Blender textures to object and importing the objects into unity

Tags: unity

I have several objects which are close to one another but not joined to "one object" They  all have their separate UVs unwrapped nicely and I would like to export the objects with the textures and materials attached to the object into unity without sacrificing the quality of the texture or making any difference in the way light reflects off of the UVs, could someone guide me through this process please?